# Timed event with Flurry with custom time and ability to cancel event

Tags: android, flurry, flurry-analytics

I want to use timed events in flurry. But i wonder is it has ability to set manually time for event. I need this to subtract the pause time from the event.

And if i start timed event (`logEvent(String eventId, boolean timed)`) can i cancel `this` event (for example is it not finished)? 
How i understand if i don't call `endTimedEvent(String eventId)` flurry will stop it himself and send it to flurry. I want to cancel event and don't send it flurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The setup you would like to accomplish with your timed events is not possible with the current SDK. Once you start the timed event, it is ended either by your use of the endTimeEvent call, or automatically at the sessions's end. In either case, it is not possible to delete the timed event so it does not log, or to manually adjust the time to accommodate a pause.